# Locking on file locations in a large Python project

Tags: python

When a Python project gets big, certain code segments, such as utility functions, tend to be run from various locations:

- from a `__main__`
- from a django server process
- from a test in a test suite

In each case the working directory for the python interpreter may be different and assuming the project spans over a sub-directory tree, the following line doesn't always work:

```
with open('some_file.xml','r') as my_xml:
```

It doesn't work because `some_file.xml` isn't always in your working directory. You need to be specific regarding the file's location, however, the project may be deployed in various environments so simply adding the directory to the `open` statement isn't a good solution.

What would be an elegant and efficient way to "lock on" the location of the file throughout the project?

Comment: Notice that a configuration file would suffer the same ill fate as the xml file - it's a resource which doesn't always exist in the same working directory...

Comment: The difference between my question and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967688/accessing-a-file-relatively-in-python-if-you-do-not-know-your-starting-point) is that the code can't assume a priori what the working directory is within the project directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the following variable to get the directory of the project may help

```
 __file__
```

[How to make a python program path independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277665/how-to-make-a-python-program-path-independent)

Comment: Although I don't want to assume anything about the working directory, your suggestion will work, because: I do need the project's root in the PYTHONPATH anyway, therefore I can always reach the files at the root of the project and there `__file__` can be used - thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967688/accessing-a-file-relatively-in-python-if-you-do-not-know-your-starting-point/1967692#1967692) also helps with how to use `__file__`

Comment: or else you can always use a properties file with setup specific filePaths and load according to the setup on which the app is deployed. wrt JAVA : maven lets you create profiles of various setups which can be used as placeholders in the properties file that get replaced on each build. I think distutils lets you do the same for python